# how to remove default graphic assigned to a control (like buttons and checkboxes) before setting new graphic to that control in java fx scene builder?

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

i am making a java desktop application using javafx. For gui building i am using scene builder 2.0.
Everything is just perfect as expected just 1 thing. I want to customize the buttons. i want to assign a custom graphic to a button.

When i use [button.setgraphic(node)] , this statement set the new graphic to the button but default graphic of button also remains present as well.

I just want to remove the default graphic and then want to assign the new (custom) garaphic to a control like buttons and radio buttons in javafx. 1 thing again i must tell that i am using scene  builder for building gui.

How can i achieve this ?
thanks in advance....

Below is the screen-shot of current occuring situation, .....

[image]

Here i have made a button using javafx scene builder , and then in the controller of the fxml file (.java file) i am trying to set the image (shown in orange box in snapshot) to that button by using setGraphics property of button ..... i just need that button to be of following shape ...

[image]

Comment: Pictures would be helpful

Comment: I have added snapshots dear .....

Answer (score 0):

You'd better customize your button via CSS. Here goes [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm). What you are trying to do is to modify button picture (which is empty by default). I guess this wasn't your exact purpose.

Comment: THanks xuesheng, i have tried your suggession, but still above mentioned behaviour, and now i want to customize the radio buttons ,in case of radio buttons , css totally not working at all to customize the shape ....

Comment: what selectors did you use for radio buttons?

Comment: i am simply following the tutorial as you suggested , and writing a css file in which there is a class called .customRadioButton , and in this i am setting the background image using fx-background property , but its showing no change on radio button...

Comment: did you apply the style to the control? `radioBtn.getStyleClass().add("customRadioButton");`

Comment: are you shure that your css file was loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

button.setGraphic(null) 
// worked for me.